# symfony doctrine:insert-sql - "Couldn't locate driver named mysql" error

Tags: symfony1, wamp, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4

hey, I am a newbie in symfony.
I am following this joobet tutorial on symfony-project.com, I am on there day 3 http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03
Whenever I type php symfony doctrine:insert-sql, I get the
following error:

doctrine creating tables
Couldn't locate driver named mysql

I am using it on WAMP. I have symfony present at C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\symfony
and my project is present in C:\wamp\www\jobeet
Kindly help me resolve this, as I am stuck here, and cant move further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the mysql driver of PDO. You will need to edit 1 or 2 php.ini files, depending on your system.

First you need to edit the php.ini apache uses, you can find it by creating a new file that does a phpinfo(), checking it via a browser and searching for "php.ini".

The second one is the one the command line uses, open a terminal (start - run - cmd.exe), and run `php -i > phpinfo.txt`, then open the text file and search for "php.ini".

You are looking for the extensions part of it, uncomment the line with pdo_mysql (remove the ; at the beginning). After all these, restart apache and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I run, check_configuration.pph, it gives me following:

  OK        PDO is installed
[[WARNING]] PDO has some drivers installed: : FAILED
            *** Install PDO drivers (mandatory for Propel and Doctrine) ***

What shall I do now?

Comment: where as in phpinfo() it says:
PDO

PDO support enabled

PDO drivers  mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL enabled

Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 
1.3.2.27 $

Persistent cache enabled

put_hits  0

put_misses  0

get_hits  0

get_misses  0

size  2000

free_items  2000

references  2


Directive Local Value Master Value

pdo_mysql.cache_size 2000 2000

Comment: Keep in mind that apache and the command line possibly use different php.ini files. You need to edit the one the CLI uses, I described above how to find it.

Comment: Slightly easier way to find the location of php.ini would be to use the command: php -i | grep "php.ini"